# perl : making a script as efficient as a perl one-liner

Tags: perl

I'm able to do this on the command line and it works :

```
~/Tools/perl/edif_extr_cell.pl design.edif nmos1p8v | perl -p -e 's/^/\n/ if /portImplementation|figure\s+device/;' | perl -n -000 -e 'print if /portImplementation/;'
```

(basically, extracting a section of the EDIF file).

Now, I want to make a utility of this. And my script is below. Question : can this code be more efficient? If feel like it's very inelegant. I could pipe streams easily on the command line but, in a script, I feel lost.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w -p

BEGIN{ $file = '';}

s/^/\n/ if /portImplementation|figure\s+device/;
$file .= $_;

END{ 
    $cmd = q{\rm -f /tmp/dump}.$$.'.txt';
    system( $cmd );
    open( OUT, ">/tmp/dump$$.txt");
    print OUT $file;
    close OUT;
    $out = `perl -n -000 -e 'print if /portImplementation/;' /tmp/dump$$.txt`;
    system( $cmd );
    print $out;
}
```

Comment: Could you post a (simplified) input sample?

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correct, you want to be able to do

```
~/Tools/perl/edif_extr_cell.pl design.edif nmos1p8v | myfilter
```

Ideally, you'd merge the two Perl scripts into one rather than having one script launch two instances of Perl, but this turns out to be rather hard because of the change to `$/` (via `-00`) and because you insert newlines in the first filter.

The simplest answer:

```
#!/bin/sh
perl -pe's/^/\n/ if /portImplementation|figure\s+device/' |
   perl -00ne'print if /portImplementation/'
```

It appears that you were trying to write the equivalent of that `sh` script in Perl. It would look like the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use IPC::Open qw( open3 );

# open3 has issues with lexical file handles.

pipe(local *PIPE_READER, local *PIPE_WRITER)
   or die($!);

my $pid1 = open3('<&STDIN', '>&PIPE_WRITER', '>&STDERR',
   'perl', '-pes/^/\n/ if /portImplementation|figure\s+device/');

my $pid2 = open3('<&PIPE_READER', '>&STDOUT', '>&STDERR',
   'perl', '-00neprint if /portImplementation/');

waitpid($pid1);
waitpid($pid2);
```

I'd normally recommend IPC::Run3 or IPC::Run for launching and interfacing with child processes, but low-level `open3` does the trick nicely in this particular situation.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded a random EDIF file from [GitHub](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dhirajt/common-digital-gates/master/NOR_Gate/design.edif), running the following script on it gives the same output as your code:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my @buffer;
my $found;
my $prepend = q();

while (<>) {

    if (/portImplementation|figure\s+device/) {
        if ($found && @buffer) {
            print $prepend, @buffer;
            $prepend = "\n";
        }
        undef $found;
        @buffer = ();
    }

    $found ||= /portImplementation/;
    push @buffer, $_;
}

# Don't forget to output the last paragraph!
print $prepend, @buffer if $found && @buffer;
```

Comment: What about the effect of paragraph mode (`-00`)? You need to flush the buffer on empty lines.

Comment: @ikegami: In the input file, the only empty lines were the ones created by the previous substitution.

Comment: I don't believe that's true in general, or even in the OP's case. The code seems clearly designed to avoid printing other elements at the same level as `portImplementation`

Comment: @ikegami: That's why I asked for sample input.